# Botão com imagem e texto

Tags: android

Tenho um botão que tem os contornos redondos e quando é seleccionado muda de cor. A esse botão está associado um determinado texto. Acontece que pretendo que no botão apareça uma imagem mais o texto e não estou a conseguir fazer.

```
<Button
    android:text="Texto"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshape4_selector"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:textColor="#B56EB6"
    android:textSize="12dp"/>
```

Aqui está o código do `roundshape4_selector` usado para quando o botão é premido mudar de cor

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/roundshape4_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/roundshape4" />
</selector>
```

**roundshape4_pressed**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/pink"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
</shape>
```

É aqui que estou a tentar colocar a imagem através da tag `<img scr="@drawable/imagem48"></img>` mas só aparece o texto.

**roundshape4**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <img scr="@drawable/imagem48"></img>
    <corners android:radius="10dip" />
    <stroke android:color="@color/pink"
        android:width="6dip"></stroke>
    <solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>
</shape>
```

Como posso fazer para que no botão me apareça a imagem e o texto ao mesmo tempo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível adicionar uma imagem a um botão recorrendo aos seguintes atributos:

```
android:drawableLeft
android:drawableRight
android:drawableTop
android:drawableBottom
```

Exemplo para colocar uma imagem posicionada no lado esquerdo(*left*) do texto:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
    ... />
```

Mais info na [documentação.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)